# Tailwind react carousel only works with using images from images.unsplash, cannot get it to work with local images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using a react carousel from https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/carousel

The carousel renders with the stock images but it is not rendering when I use my local images, or even images from another other source hosted online. Why is this? How can I make it work for local images?

I've tried to change:

```
src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493246507139-91e8fad9978e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2940&q=80"
```

to: src="./images/image1"

&

src="../images/image1"

and I've even tried to import the image using both paths incase I was incorrect and it won't render.

Full code below:

```
import { Carousel, Typography, Button } from "@material-tailwind/react";
 
export function CarouselWithContent() {
  return (
    <Carousel className="rounded-xl">
      <div className="relative h-full w-full">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497436072909-60f360e1d4b1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2560&q=80"
          alt="image 1"
          className="h-full w-full object-cover"
        />
        <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full place-items-center bg-black/75">
          <div className="w-3/4 text-center md:w-2/4">
            <Typography
              variant="h1"
              color="white"
              className="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl"
            >
              The Beauty of Nature
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="lead"
              color="white"
              className="mb-12 opacity-80"
            >
              It is not so much for its beauty that the forest makes a claim
              upon men&apos;s hearts, as for that subtle something, that quality
              of air that emanation from old trees, that so wonderfully changes
              and renews a weary spirit.
            </Typography>
            <div className="flex justify-center gap-2">
              <Button size="lg" color="white">
                Explore
              </Button>
              <Button size="lg" color="white" variant="text">
                Gallery
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="relative h-full w-full">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493246507139-91e8fad9978e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2940&q=80"
          alt="image 2"
          className="h-full w-full object-cover"
        />
        <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full items-center bg-black/75">
          <div className="w-3/4 pl-12 md:w-2/4 md:pl-20 lg:pl-32">
            <Typography
              variant="h1"
              color="white"
              className="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl"
            >
              The Beauty of Nature
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="lead"
              color="white"
              className="mb-12 opacity-80"
            >
              It is not so much for its beauty that the forest makes a claim
              upon men&apos;s hearts, as for that subtle something, that quality
              of air that emanation from old trees, that so wonderfully changes
              and renews a weary spirit.
            </Typography>
            <div className="flex gap-2">
              <Button size="lg" color="white">
                Explore
              </Button>
              <Button size="lg" color="white" variant="text">
                Gallery
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="relative h-full w-full">
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518623489648-a173ef7824f3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2762&q=80"
          alt="image 3"
          className="h-full w-full object-cover"
        />
        <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full items-end bg-black/75">
          <div className="w-3/4 pl-12 pb-12 md:w-2/4 md:pl-20 md:pb-20 lg:pl-32 lg:pb-32">
            <Typography
              variant="h1"
              color="white"
              className="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl"
            >
              The Beauty of Nature
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              variant="lead"
              color="white"
              className="mb-12 opacity-80"
            >
              It is not so much for its beauty that the forest makes a claim
              upon men&apos;s hearts, as for that subtle something, that quality
              of air that emanation from old trees, that so wonderfully changes
              and renews a weary spirit.
            </Typography>
            <div className="flex gap-2">
              <Button size="lg" color="white">
                Explore
              </Button>
              <Button size="lg" color="white" variant="text">
                Gallery
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Carousel>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the images in `public` folder ( when you create a react app using `Vite` then it creates a folder called public folder in the project). And then you can just use that path in the `src` attribute of the `<image/>` as shown below.

[image]

// CarouselWithContent.jsx file

```
import { Carousel, Typography, Button } from "@material-tailwind/react";

export function CarouselWithContent() {
    return (
        <Carousel className="rounded-xl">
            <div className="relative h-full w-full">
                <img
                    src="/first_img.jpg"
                    alt="image 1"
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                />
                <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full place-items-center bg-black/75">
                    <div className="w-3/4 text-center md:w-2/4">
                        <Typography
                            variant="h1"
                            color="white"
                            className="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl"
                        >
                            The Beauty of Nature
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            variant="lead"
                            color="white"
                            className="mb-12 opacity-80"
                        >
                            It is not so much for its beauty that the forest makes a claim
                            upon men&apos;s hearts, as for that subtle something, that quality
                            of air that emanation from old trees, that so wonderfully changes
                            and renews a weary spirit.
                        </Typography>
                        <div className="flex justify-center gap-2">
                            <Button size="lg" color="white">
                                Explore
                            </Button>
                            <Button size="lg" color="white" variant="text">
                                Gallery
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="relative h-full w-full">
                <img
                    src="/second_img.jpg"
                    alt="image 2"
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                />
                <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full items-center bg-black/75">
                    <div className="w-3/4 pl-12 md:w-2/4 md:pl-20 lg:pl-32">
                        <Typography
                            variant="h1"
                            color="white"
                            className="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl"
                        >
                            The Beauty of Nature
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            variant="lead"
                            color="white"
                            className="mb-12 opacity-80"
                        >
                            It is not so much for its beauty that the forest makes a claim
                            upon men&apos;s hearts, as for that subtle something, that quality
                            of air that emanation from old trees, that so wonderfully changes
                            and renews a weary spirit.
                        </Typography>
                        <div className="flex gap-2">
                            <Button size="lg" color="white">
                                Explore
                            </Button>
                            <Button size="lg" color="white" variant="text">
                                Gallery
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="relative h-full w-full">
                <img
                    src="/third_img.jpg"
                    alt="image 3"
                    className="h-full w-full object-cover"
                />
                <div className="absolute inset-0 grid h-full w-full items-end bg-black/75">
                    <div className="w-3/4 pl-12 pb-12 md:w-2/4 md:pl-20 md:pb-20 lg:pl-32 lg:pb-32">
                        <Typography
                            variant="h1"
                            color="white"
                            className="mb-4 text-3xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl"
                        >
                            The Beauty of Nature
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            variant="lead"
                            color="white"
                            className="mb-12 opacity-80"
                        >
                            It is not so much for its beauty that the forest makes a claim
                            upon men&apos;s hearts, as for that subtle something, that quality
                            of air that emanation from old trees, that so wonderfully changes
                            and renews a weary spirit.
                        </Typography>
                        <div className="flex gap-2">
                            <Button size="lg" color="white">
                                Explore
                            </Button>
                            <Button size="lg" color="white" variant="text">
                                Gallery
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Carousel>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm using create react app for this and I cannot get the images to work in the public folder. I had an images folder in src but removed it to try it this way and I'm getting error:

ERROR in ./src/App.js 13:0-38
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /public/about.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

For all of the image I'm trying to use

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to move my carousel component out of a component folder to get this to work. For whatever reason, no path would work from an images folder and a component folder I had to have one or the other. These kinds of things only seem to happen in Create-react-app which I won't be using anymore. Thanks